# Postgis / Elixir Geo. Location results are correct. But longitude is getting changed

Tags: postgis, elixir, ecto

I'm storing this value `%Geo.Point{coordinates: {10.78639, 106.70095}, srid: nil}`, but when I query (the result is correct distance-wise), the the returned value has a different lng. `%Geo.Point{coordinates: {10.78639, 73.29905}, srid: 4326}`.

The original is near Saigon, Vietnam. The new one is off the west coast of India.

Answer (score 3):

It appears PostGIS points are (longitude, latitude) not (latitude, longitude).

Thanks ambiguous documentation: [PostGIS: Is it lon/lat or lat/lon?](http://postgis.net/2013/08/18/tip_lon_lat/) a simple "It's Long,Lat" would be helpful here.

Comment: The Cartesian coordinate order (X, Y) is the same as (longitude, latitude)